# Mysql JOIN multiple columns

Tags: mysql, join

How to do this way???

Table1

```
|person_id|name|division|
```

Table2

```
|job_id|declare|person1_id|person2_id|
```

Output:

```
|job_id|declare|person1_name|person2_name|
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select t2.job_id, 
       t2.declare, 
       tp1.name as person1_name, 
       tp2.name as person2_name
from table2 t2
left join table1 tp1 on tp1.person_id = t2.person1_id
left join table1 tp2 on tp2.person_id = t2.person2_id
```

Comment: Then you applied it wrong. Differ between `t2` and `tp2`

Comment: yup... i have wrong applied it @first time :), it works but only one row output...maybe my database structure was bad...:) THX

Comment: Hard to tell without example data. I changed the `join` to a `left` join in case you have `null` values.

Comment: well the change works great.... thx alot ^_^v